# Running into a unresolved access error using Block distribution

Tags: chapel

I've been running into an error when trying to compile with Block distribution.
This is the error:

```
error: unresolved access of '[BlockDom(3,int(64),false,unmanaged DefaultDist)] real(64)' by '[int(64), int(64)]'
```

```
use Random, BlockDist;

config const size = 10;
const Space = {1..size, 1..size};

const gridSpace: domain(2) dmapped Block(boundingBox=Space);
var grid: [gridSpace] real;
var grid2: [gridSpace] real;
var grid3: [gridSpace] real;

fillRandom(grid);
fillRandom(grid2);

forall i in gridSpace do {
    forall j in gridSpace do {
        forall k in gridSpace do {
            grid3[i,j] += grid[i,k] * grid2[k,j]; //error here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When iterating over a multi-dimensional domain in Chapel with a single index, the index will have the [index type](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/language/spec/domains.html#domain-index-types) of the domain. In your example above, the distributed domain `gridSpace` is a 2-dimensional domain, therefore iterating over it with a single index will yield tuples of 2 integers.

For example,

```
var dom = {1..2, 1..2};
for idx in dom {
  writeln(idx); // index type is (int, int)
}
```

will print:

```
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
```

The error I got when compiling your example with Chapel 1.19.0 is:

```
error: unresolved access of '[BlockDom(2,int(64),false,unmanaged DefaultDist)] real(64)' by '[2*int(64), 2*int(64)]'
```

This is telling us that we are trying to index into a block-distributed 2D array (`[BlockDom(2,int(64),false,unmanaged DefaultDist)]`) of reals (`real(64)`) with 2 tuples of 2 integers (`[2*int(64), 2*int(64)]`).

One way you could correct the above example is by iterating over each dimension explicitly:

```
forall i in gridSpace.dim(1) {
    forall j in gridSpace.dim(2) {
        forall k in gridSpace.dim(1) {
            grid3[i,j] += grid[i,k] * grid2[k,j];
        }
    }
}
```

However, note that that there will be multiple iterations from the inner-most loop trying to add to same index of `grid3` in parallel, creating a data race.

You can remove this data race by making the inner loop serial:

```
forall (i,j) in gridSpace {
  for k in gridSpace.dim(2) {
    grid3[i,j] += grid[i,k] * grid2[k,j];
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a [+ reduction](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/primers/reductions.html?highlight=reduction) to handle the inner loop summation:

```
forall (i,j) in gridSpace {
  grid3[i,j] = + reduce (grid[i,..]*grid2[..,j]);
}
```

There are 2 other issues with the code above that I noticed:

1. The `gridSpace` is only defined with a type and no value, so it is actually an empty distributed domain. You can fix this by initializing it with the value of `Space`:

```
const gridSpace: domain(2) dmapped Block(boundingBox=Space) = Space;
```

See the [Distributions primer](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/primers/distributions.html#block-and-distribution-basics) for more examples.

2. The `do` is not needed in the `forall` loops above. `do` is only required when omitting the curly braces for a single-expression for loop body, e.g.

```
for i in dom do writeln(i);
```

See the [for-loops guide](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/users-guide/base/forloops.html) for more information.